# Comando require não funciona em gem para ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gem

Instalei o **Ruby**, o **RailsInstaller** e o **RubyDevKit** no na partição C (e.g. c:\Ruby23-x64).

Executo no cmd

> ruby -v

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aparece a versão do ruby instalada sem problemas.
Executo

> gem install pipedrive-ruby

e também instala sem problemas, porém quando executo

> require 'pipedrive-ruby'

dá erro de 'require' não é reconhecido como comando interno ou externo... 
Quando executo

> gem list

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o pipedrive-ruby aparece como local gem normalmente.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Estou tentando executar a gem do [pipedrive](http://github.com/GeneralScripting/pipedrive-ruby).

Comment: Você consegue adicionar o backtrace do erro aqui?

Comment: @RafaelFidelis Eu estava tentando executar o código via cmd, estava difícil executar. Simplesmente passei a utilizar um arquivo .rb. Agora deu certo, Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Na verdade, qualquer `require` de dependência de gem em ruby deve ser declarado no início do código, dentro do arquivo .rb

Um exemplo é:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
require 'date'
```

Após isso é possível usar os recursos disponíveis na gem.